# swift image/button slider

Tags: ios, swift

So I want to create a button/image slider much like the one in this video https://www.facebook.com/russellwilliamharrower/videos/2496334937321048/ However I currently am unsure how they did this in Swift.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to create row that has different images that scrolls left and right and allows users to click on an image (which is a button) - they all call the same function (just different values)

Also I don't know what the effect is called so I don't know what I should be googling to work this out.

Comment: That's a collectionView inside of a tableview cell with a custom CollectionView cell

Comment: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/